# Pathogen (Vim) non-default bundle directory location

Tags: vim, default, directory, pathogen

I like the idea of keeping all my Vim plugins and my vimrc in Dropbox. I also love pathogen. Looking at the pathogen.vim file, it seems I can provide the pathogen#infect() function with an alternative location for my bundle folder. But this just doesn't work. I've searched high and low for a solution, but nothing I do will allow me to change the 'working directory', as it were, for pathogen to '~/Dropbox/Vim/GlobalRuntimePath/bundle'. I've tried sourcing pathogen.vim directly in my vimrc, to no avail. Pathogen doesn't complain, just my vimrc when it tries to call upon functions from plugins that no longer exists when I remove their local copies.

Am I asking the wrong questions?

Answer (score 5):

There is a way for adding custom bundle directories provided in
Pathogen.  First, one should append paths to the directories containing
additional bundles to the `runtimepath` option:

```
:set runtimepath+=~/Dropbox/Vim/GlobalRuntimePath
```

Then, when loading Pathogen in `.vimrc` file, one should specify the
name of all bundle directories (they must have the same one) as the
argument to the `runtime_append_all_bundles` call:

```
:call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles('bundle')
```

If bundle directories are named by default, `bundle`, the argument can
be omitted.

Comment: Note that the methodology has changed in the latest version of pathogen, as of 2016-06-21T08:48:59. The new version states: `Change pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles('bundle') to pathogen#infect('bundle/{}')`